# emacs indentation face in command line

Tags: shell, emacs, colors, terminal, elpy

I'm editing python code using emacs, elpy and magit. When starting emacs using the -nw option (from bash and gnome-terminal in gnome 3). When started this way, emacs highlight the indented blocks of code using a black background single character; when using a graphic display (without the -nw option), the same character is a light gray. Please check out the two attached screenshots:

[image: in graphical mode]

[image: in terminal]

Is there a way to modify the darkness of the face in order make it less prominent?

Comment: I've managed to change the face using the following steps: 1 - place the cursor on the indented block; 2 - `M-x` `costumize-face`; 3 - select the default value (`highlight-indentation-face`); 4 - select `Show all` (the face inherit from `fringes`); 5 - tick `Background`; 6 - `Choose` `gray`; would it be possible to place all this in the `.emacs` file wen elpy is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solutions that works. I'm not sure if it's the best one: if anybody knows a better way to do this, please comment!

In short:

1. Place the cursor on the indented block;
2. `M-x` `customize-face`;
3. Select the default value (`highlight-indentation-face`);
4. Select `Show all` (the face inherit from `fringes`);
5. Tick `Background` (this will overwrite the fringe background color);
6. Choose the white color (which is aliased to #e5e5e5)
7. Press `Apply and Save`

The last step will write few lines to the ~/.emacs file (on linux) to preserve the customization values. In my system, the lines that were added are:

```
(custom-set-variables)
(custom-set-faces
  '(highlight-indentation-face ((t (:inherit fringe :background "white")))))
```

Comment: Looks good to me. A suggestion would be to use the variable `custom-file`, setting it to a different file from your init file (`~/.emacs`). It's good to separate code that you write and manage from code that Customize writes and manages automatically. See the Emacs manual, node [Saving Customizations](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Customizations.html).